# AWS Cloud formation add multiple layers to lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have added one layer to my Lambda function through CloudFormation. Now I have a requirement to add one more layer to my function. Basically, I need two layers in my existing Lambda function. Is it possible?  I tried searching the AWS docs but I don't see it.

```yaml
Resources:
  LambdaLayer:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion"
    Properties:
    CompatibleRuntimes:
    - python3.8
    Content:
    S3Bucket: !Sub "hello-${AWS::Region}"
    S3Key: !Sub "myapp/layer1.zip"
    LayerName: "layer1"

  LambdaFunction:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
    Code:
    S3Bucket: hello
    S3Key: myapp/function.zip"
    FunctionName: "hello-function"
    Handler: "hello-function.lambda_handler"
    Layers:
    - !Ref LambdaLayer
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, is it possible.  Add additional layers in the same way that you did the first layer, only append numbers to the resource names to distinguish them:

```yaml
Resources:
  LambdaLayer1:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion"
    Properties:
    CompatibleRuntimes:
    - python3.8
    Content:
      S3Bucket: !Sub "hello-${AWS::Region}"
      S3Key: !Sub "myapp/layer1.zip"
    LayerName: "layer1"
  
  LambdaLayer2:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion"
    ...
    LayerName: "layer2"

 LambdaFunction:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
    Code:
      S3Bucket: hello
      S3Key: myapp/function.zip"
    FunctionName: "hello-function"
    Handler: "hello-function.lambda_handler"
    Layers:
    - !Ref LambdaLayer1
    - !Ref LambdaLayer2
```